# Pushing old code to git repository

Tags: git

I'm new to git. I have remote git repo on my server which contains master which is the current version of my code. On my local computer I have old versions (about 10) of this code just stored elsewhere from before I was using version control (just plain files).

Even though I probably will never need the old versions again, I'd still like to add them to the repo so if I ever wanted to check an old version I could do that.

So how do I do this, do I add them as branches or tags and how should I go about adding them to the remote repo?

Right now I do this: just delete ALL the current version code (already committed and pushed to server), copy and paste in the old code files (say version 0.2) and create new branch (version0.2), commit that and then push to server. Now I got 2 branches, master and version0.2. Should this be the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is fine, however if the old code actually lead to where master is I'd recommend stitching everything together into a single branch once all the code is in the repository. I'm  assuming that this is a private repository and messing with master isn't going to effect anybody else (rewriting history on a public repository isn't nice).

That being said I also assume you have a bunch of branches similar to the following branches:

1. v0.1
2. v0.2
3. v0.3
4. master

In this case v0.1 is the oldest, v0.2 built on v0.1, and so on. To actually make master represent this I suggest rebasing branches in order so that at the end master contains the code from all the branches. The steps to do this are:

1. `git checkout v0.2`
2. `git checkout -b REBASE_v0.2`

   - By creating a new branch, named REBASE, here we don't effect the original v0.2 branch. If something goes wrong we can always revert to the old branch.
3. `git rebase v0.1`
4. Solve any conflicts.
5. If you removed any files between v0.1 and v0.2 `git rm FILE` each file.
6. `git checkout v0.3`
7. `git checkout -b REBASE_v0.3`
8. `git rebase REBASE_v0.2`
9. Solve any conflicts
10. If you removed any files between v0.2 and v0.3 `git rm FILE` each file.
11. Rinse and repeat steps 6-10 for any more version branches you've imported.
12. `git checkout master`
13. `git checkout -b REBASE_master`
14. `git rebase REBASE_v0.3`
15. Solve any conflicts
16. `git diff master`

    - Assuming all conflicts were resolved correctly this should show no differences.
17. `git checkout master`
18. `git branch master_old`
19. `git reset --hard REBASE_master`
20. `git branch -D REBASE_v0.2 REBASE_v0.3 REBASE_master`

    - Get rid of the rebase branches

Once you're certain that everything is good you can go ahead and get rid of original branches: `git branch -D v0.1 v0.2 v0.3 master_old`

At this point you should just have a master branch with your actual code progression.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do:

1. Find all your old versions and sort them by age
2. Create a repository in the oldest one and commit
3. Replace all the files with the second oldest version and commit
4. Repeat until you have committed all versions
5. From a clone of your remote repo, pull this new repository
6. Resolve merge conflict by keeping the newest version and commit

Or if you are the only user of your remote repository, it is even cleaner to apply the newest commits from the remote repo on top of the old versions, and replace the remote repo.